# Angular : How to access the indexes - key values in array

Tags: angular

I have populated an array as

```
dataList[SN] = 'REQ123';
array.push(dataList);
dataList[T] = '123123';
array.push(dataList);
```

Now I am having the array structured like this

```
array = [[SN:REQ123],[T:123123]];
```

I have iterated through each record using forEach loop

I got the first element as [SN:REQ123]

Here, how can I access the key and the values (i.e, SN and REQ123)?

I tried keys method but it returns an array iterator. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a full snippet on how exactly that structure gets generated? Something I can copy paste into the console would be great

Comment: What's the problem with using the Array iterator ? In your case, you don't even need to loop through the array. Just refer the 1st element and you're good.

Comment: @DelwynPinto when I used item[0] to access SN it said undefined. If i use item[SN] it prints REQ123. The key and values are not static. So I want to know how to get these keys and values

Comment: @thillaiselvan, can you share the exact structure in json format ? if format is like this [[SN:REQ123],[T:123123]] , is first element array or object ? and "SN:REQ123" is a string ?

Answer (score 0):

An array is a structure that contains only values i.e. it cannot by definition contain keys. The structure that you have is an array, but each of its elements has a key-value pair, making each element an object. Therefore, the premise of the question is inaccurate.

What you need, is a way to access the keys of individual elements in an array of JSON objects.

You can do that by looping through the array & using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in each loop like such

```
array.forEach(el => {

    //el will be [SN:REQ123]
    
    var key = Object.keys(el);
    //key will be [SN]
});
```

Do note that Object.keys() will return an array, even if there is only a single key.